# objective-c simple error code '('

Tags: objective-c

```
@interface ViewController ()

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *rollButtonClicked;

-(IBaction)rollButtonClicked:(id)sender 

{
    int roll = [self.model getDiceRoll];
    int roll2 = [self.model getDiceRoll];

    [self.firstDieView showDie:roll];
    [self.secondDieView showDieroll2];

    NSString *sumText = [NSString stringWithFromat:@"Sum is %d", roll + roll2];

    self.sumLabel.text = sumText;

}
```

i keep getting errors, if i place a semi colon after
-(IBaction)rollButtonClicked:(id)sender i will get '(' and if i remove it xcode will show me issue because it says i need a semi colon after 
-(IBaction)rollButtonClicked:(id)sender

as you can see i'm still very new at Object-C please help

thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You're working in the header file (`.h`).

There you must only declare the function like so:

```
- (IBaction)rollButtonClicked:(id)sender;
```

In your implementation file (`.m`) add your code:

```
- (IBaction)rollButtonClicked:(id)sender {
    int roll = [self.model getDiceRoll];
    int roll2 = [self.model getDiceRoll];

    [self.firstDieView showDie:roll];
    [self.secondDieView showDieroll2];

    NSString *sumText = [NSString stringWithFromat:@"Sum is %d", roll + roll2];

    self.sumLabel.text = sumText;
}
```